# Accesing https json api returns nil each time (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to access Flickr api using this code in Swift, while I print jsonData variable, it prints the data in binary format

```
 var error = NSError()
 var api_url = NSURL.URLWithString("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=car&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=json")
 let jsonData: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(api_url, options: nil, error: nil)
 let result:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
 return result
```

but my app crashes on result variable **Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** help! much appreciated.

Comment: If dataWithContentsOfURL fails, it will return nil. I would first try using that error object you have and see if there's any errors if you determine that the data is nil.

Comment: But the error comes from result variable and not from jsonData variable, to double check I printed jsonData and it's not empty.

Comment: So how about using the error object for the NSJSONSerialization? Looks like you have that error object, but aren't using it for anything... Put that thing to use! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour with Flickr API. JSON response comes with callback function wrapper.

To disable it add `&nojsoncallback=1` at the end of your url.

Official docs:
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

Since the raw JSON is wrapped with function wrapper, your `NSJSONSerialization` is returning nil.